# sql inner table substitution

Tags: sql, oracle11g, subquery

Suppose I have an sql query like the following (I realize this query could be written better, just bear with me):

```
SELECT aT.NAME 
FROM   anothertable aT, 
   ( SELECT ts.slot_id, 
                 tgm.trans_id,
                 tagm.agent_id 
          FROM   slots ts, 
                 transactions tgm, 
                 agents tagm 
          WHERE  ts.slot_id = (12345, 678910) 
          and    ts.slot_id = tagm.slot_id 
          AND    ts.slot_id = tgm.slot_id) INNER 
WHERE  INNER.trans_id = aT.trans_id
       AND INNER.agent_id = aT.trans_id
```

Now suppose that I need to break up this query into two parts...in the first I'll execute the inner query, do some processing on the results in code, and then pass back a reduced set to the outer part of the query.  The question is, is there an easy way to emulate an inner table in sql?
For instance, if the results of the inner query returned 5 rows but my program deems to only need two of those rows, how can I write sql that will do what I am trying to do below?  Is there a way, in sql, to declare a table for in memory in query use?

```
SELECT 
    at.Name
FROM
    anotherTable aT,
    (SLOT_ID, TRANS_ID, AGENT_ID
     -------------------------
    230743,  3270893,  2307203
    078490,   230897,   237021) inner
WHERE
   inner.trans_id = at.trans_id
   AND INNER.agent_id = aT.trans_id
```

Comment: use a `temptabe` most of RDBMSs have that feature.

Comment: What database are you using?  You should tag the question appropriately.

Comment: Using Oracle (tags updated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a subquery:

```
SELECT at.Name
FROM anotherTable aT JOIN
    (select 230743 as SLOT_ID,  3270893 as TRANS_ID,  2307203 as AGENT_ID from dual
     select 078490,   230897,   237021 from dual
    ) i
    on i.trans_id = at.trans_id AND i.agent_id = aT.trans_id;
```

Comment: Since this is Oracle, the syntax seems to be:
            select 230743 as SLOT_ID,  3270893 as TRANS_ID,  2307203 as AGENT_ID FROM DUAL 
        union
            select 078490,   230897,   237021

Comment: @user3225509 . . . This was not labelled as Oracle when I answered.  I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most systems will let you define a TEMP TABLE or TABLE VARIABLE: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/

```
CREATE TABLE #temp ( 
  SLOT_ID INT,
  TRANS_ID INT,
  AGENT_ID INT
);

INSERT INTO #temp(SLOT_ID, TRANS_ID, AGENT_ID)
  (--inner query goes here)

--do your main query, then:

DROP TABLE #temp
```

IN MS SQL Server (not sure about other systems), you could possibly use a Common Table Expression (CTE): https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

```
WITH inner AS (
  --inner query goes here
)

--main select goes here
```

Personally, since I generally work with MSSQL Server, I use CTE's quite a bit, as they can be created "on the fly", and can be a big help in organizing more complex queries.

Comment: Alas, in my db, I seem to have insufficient privileges.  If I can't use the above solution to solve this problem entirely inline, I'll revisit this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery method worked.  Since this is Oracle, the syntax turned out to be:

```
SELECT aT.Name
FROM anotherTable aT,
(select 1907945 as SLOT_ID, 2732985 as TRANS_ID, 40157 as AGENT_ID FROM DUAL 
   union
 select 1907945, 2732985, 40187 FROM DUAL 
) inner
WHERE
inner.trans_id = aT.trans_id AND INNER.agent_id = aT.trans_id;
```